# Regex: find a lot of patterns in one string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
деревня Лесное, деревня Пальмово, село Поляково, город Стерлитамак
```

Desire output

```
['деревня Лесное', 'деревня Пальмово', 'село Поляково']
```

I try to use

```
villages_compiler = re.compile(r"""\b^(?:[Дд]еревня|[Сс]ело|[Рр]азъезд|[ДдСсПпХх]|[Сс]т|[Дд]ер|[Пп]ос([её]лок|[Кк]оллективный сад)?|[Пп]гт|[Рр]\.?\s?[Пп]|[Сc]адовое товарищество|ДНП|ДНТ|ДПК|ДТ|ЖК|СТ|СНТ|СПК|СО|СК)(?:\.|\s|\.\s)(?:\«?|\"?)[\w\s\.-]+(?:\»?|\"?)""" \
                               r"""|\b^[\w\s-]+(?:[Сс]ельсовет|[Шш]оссе)""")
re.findall(villages_compiler, "деревня Лесное, деревня Пальмово, село Поляково, город Стерлитамак")
```

But it returns an empty list.
When I change `findall()` to `search()` I get only `деревня Лесное`

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: `villages_compiler.findall(input_string)`

Comment: I assume you're using python 3+?

Comment: @Chillie yes, you're right

Comment: @PetrPetrov I've updated my answer, let me know if that solves it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2:

Make sure you removed both `^`s from and that you changed the weird group mentioned previously to non-capturing.

```
s = 'деревня Лесное, деревня Пальмово, село Поляково, город Стерлитамак'
expr = r'\b(?:[Дд]еревня|[Сс]ело|[Рр]азъезд|[ДдСсПпХх]|[Сс]т|[Дд]ер|[Пп]ос(?:[её]лок|[Кк]оллективный сад)?|[Пп]гт|[Рр]\.?\s?[Пп]|[Сc]адовое товарищество|ДНП|ДНТ|ДПК|ДТ|ЖК|СТ|СНТ|СПК|СО|СК)(?:\.|\s|\.\s)(?:\«?|\"?)[\w\s\.-]+(?:\»?|\"?)|\b[\w\s-]+(?:[Сс]ельсовет|[Шш]оссе)'

re.findall(expr, s)
```

Gives me the following output in python 3.6:

```
['деревня Лесное', 'деревня Пальмово', 'село Поляково']
```

Same with

```
comp = re.compile(expr)
comp.findall(s)
```

Please make sure that you are running this in python 3+ and that you don't have any typos in your regex.

Edit:

1. As stated previously you need to get rid of the `^`s in your pattern.
2. You made this `[Пп]ос([её]лок|[Кк]оллективный сад)?` a capturing group and the group bracket placement seems weird too.

I ended up with [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ewtIsU/2) (keeping the weird group but making it non-capturing). Let me know if it works.

Original post:
You have a `^` beginning of string character and pass only one string.

If you remove it from both places, do you get your desired output?

[Regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/ewtIsU/1)

Also, [as per docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.search) search only looks for the first location of the pattern.

Comment: It returns me `['', '', '']` with `villages_compiler.findall(your_string)`

Comment: @PetrPetrov updated. Check for any capturing groups left, since you get three zero-length results.

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

As @nhahtdh said there is a method `findall` of `villages_compiler`, so:

```
villages_compiler.findall(your_string)
```

Comment: It also returns empty list